# Using ML model on biased data

Tags: model, bias

Have ML model (gradient boosting) trained on *n* features. For example, one of these *n* features is *region*. Looked at feature importances - it is one of the most important features (by split).
The problem is that data that needs to be scored is biased - the feature *region* has only one value in it.
Is it a problem? Why? What is the best thing to do here: train new model leaving this *region* feature behind?

Answer (score 0):

If the feature is constant, has only one level, don't use it, since it brings no information to the model. Just drop this feature from your data.

If the feature importance algorithm marks this feature as very important, I'd not trust the feature importance algorithm that you are using.